# How to update a fields in a piece

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Hello all I want to update fields in piece. I have a piece that name idea, I want to update status field on accepted when user click on accept and refused else but i didn't succeed. My code is like this:

`idees.html`

```
<div class="bradcam_area breadcam_bg overlay2">
<h3>Gestion des idees</h3>
</div>
{% for piece in data.pieces %}
{% if piece.status == "En attente" %}
<section class="sample-text-area">
  <div class="container box_1170">
      <h3 class="text-heading">{{ piece.title }}</h3>
      <p class="sample-text">{{piece.description}}</p>
      <div class="button-group-area mt-40">
        <a  id="accepteButton" href="{{apos.gidee.updateIdee(piece,'accepte')}}" class="genric-btn primary circle arrow">Accepter<span class="lnr lnr-arrow-right"></span></a>
        <a href="{{apos.gidee.updateIdee(piece,'refuse')}}" class="genric-btn danger circle arrow">Refuser<span class="lnr lnr-arrow-right"></span></a>
        <a href="{{ piece._url }}" class="genric-btn success circle arrow">En savoir plus<span class="lnr lnr-arrow-right"></span></a>
        </div>
  </div>


</section>
{% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

and `index.js`

```
module.exports = {
      extend: 'apostrophe-pieces-pages',
        alias: 'gidee',
      construct: function(self, options) {

       self.addHelpers({
           updateIdee: function(idee,etat) {

        self.beforeSave = function(req, idee, options, callback) {
                idee.status = etat;
                return callback();
           };
            return '';
         }

     });

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helper functions are for use in nunjucks templates and do not have any role in handling requests, such as responding to the click.

beforeSave is a lifecycle callback and is invoked when Apostrophe is already about to save a piece. You have it in the wrong module (it wold go in your pieces module, not your pieces-pages module), but even then, you are not doing anything to actually trigger a save operation.

What you really want here is a custom route, in **your pieces module, not your pieces-pages module**:

```
// lib/modules/gidees/index.js

const choices = [
  {
    label: 'unknown',
    value: ''
  },
  {
    label: 'refuse',
    value: 'refuse'
  },
  {
    label: 'accepte',
    value: 'accepte'
  }
];

module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
  name: 'gidee',
  addFields: [
    {
      name: 'status',
      type: 'select',
      choices
    }  
  ],
  construct: function(self, options) {
    // Add a POST route
    self.route('post', 'status', async function(req, res) {
      const _id = self.apos.launder.id(req.body._id);
      const status = self.apos.launder.select(req.body.status, choices);
      const piece = await self.find(req, { _id }).toObject();
      if (!piece) {
        return res.status(404).send('not found');
      }
      if (!piece._edit) {
        return res.status(401).send('unauthorized');
      }
      await self.apos.docs.db.update({
        _id
      }, {
        $set: {
          status
        }
      });
      return res.send('ok');
    });
  }
};
```

Now you have a route that the browser can send a POST request to, but you still need frontend JavaScript code to actually do that. It is technically possible to do this with a plain link using the GET method, but that creates unnecessary CSRF risks.

Here's what you need to do this in your `show.html` template:

```
{# in lib/modules/gidee-pages/views/show.html #}

{# For context: notice that we have access to the piece here #}
<h1>{{ data.piece.title }}</h1>

{# status change buttons appear only if you have the privilege of editing the piece #}
{% if data.piece._edit %}
  <button data-review-id="{{ data.piece._id }}" data-review-choice="accepte">Accepter</button>
  <button data-review-id="{{ data.piece._id }}" data-review-choice="refuse">Refuse</button>

<script>
$(function() {
  // Bind click handler to body but filter it to only pay attention to clicks
  // on the buttons with a data-review-id attribute
  $('body').on('click', '[data-review-id]', function() {
    // ES5 syntax for IE11, you can use ES6 if you have a babel-based frontend build
    // in your project
    var _id = $(this).attr('data-review-id');
    var status = $(this).attr('data-review-choice');
    // Make a POST request, send the parameters as JSON
    $.jsonCall('/modules/gidee/status', {
      _id: _id,
      status: status
    }, function() {
      // It worked, show this with jquery code of your choice
    }, function() {
      // It did not work, show this with jquery code of your choice
    });
    // "return false" prevents default action of clicking on the button
    return false;
  });
})
</script>
{% endif %}
```

It's not 100% clear in your question, but this answer assumes that the user in question has the privilege of editing the piece already and so we don't need to make any exceptions to the permissions model to implement this.